# Changing the default SQL developer icon [Applications]

Tags: icons, appmenu, sql, sqldeveloper

**Note below solution**

The following answer is a way of changing the default sqldeveloper icon into something more exciting and less out of place within the sharpness and sleekness of the Ubuntu interface.

Answer (score 0):

This process assumes you have installed SQL developer already and have created the desktop shortcut to expose SQL dev onto the applications menu.

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
```

The below was added to the sqldeveloper.desktop file etcetera.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=sqldeveloper
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;Oracle;
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
```

Below is the default icon which comes with the SQL package is blurry and unappealing.

[image: sql_dev_original_icon]

**Step 1:** Download a new icon of your choice, preferably one with an alpha background or in other words set to transparent.
**Step 2:** Locate the position of the original icon using the following terminal commands:

```
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/ && ls -l
```

[image: sql_dev_icon_path_location]

**Step 3:** Either remove the original icon named icon.png or copy the new downloaded png file to the sqldeveloper directory using:

```
sudo cp Pictures/icon_2.png /opt/sqldeveloper/
```

[change the new icon name to avoid confusion]

**Step 4:** Remove the file named icon.png if you kept it using:

```
sudo rm icon.png
```

then rename the new file to icon.png

```
mv icon_2.png icon.png
```

Finally check the application menu after restarting Ubuntu

[image]